# Date from one format to other in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have this input : 2015-01-03 16:29:05
Need to get the output as Jan 03 2015 16:29:05
Please help me get this using Javascript.
Tried converting the input to Date object using new Date(). But it showed error saying invalid date.

Comment: `new Date('2015-01-03 16:29:05');` Works fine for me.  See the [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Deconstruct:

```
var parsed = input.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)$/);
if( !parsed) throw new Error("Could not parse date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss");
```

Then reconstruct:

```
var monthstr = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
var output = monthstr.substr((parsed[2]-1)*3,3)+
       " "+parsed[3]+" "+parsed[1]+
       " "+parsed[4];
```

You may be interested in [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/) for more advanced stuff, but for something this simple just a basic string manipulation will do.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a multiplication by 3 in that month name code, or am I still sleepy?

Comment: @Pointy Knew I was forgetting something.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use Moment.js

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, new Date() should work fine with that string. This works for me:

```
var d = new Date('2015-01-03 16:29:05');

var options = {
    year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "2-digit", 
    hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", second:  "2-digit" };

var dateStr = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', options);
var dateFormatted = dateStr.slice(3, 7) + 
                    dateStr.slice(0,2) + 
                    dateStr.slice(6);

console.log(dateFormatted); // gives 'Jan 03 2015 16:29:05'
```

Hope this helps you. Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: `Date` is locale-aware. What it outputs for you may be completely different from what it outputs for, say, someone in France.

Comment: Edited to use `toLocaleTimeString()` which should work using this approach.